# get coordinates by clicking on map HERE maps

Tags: javascript, here-api

Can I make it possible for a user to click on a map and get the coordinates of clicked place, using JavaScript?

Comment: Yup, you sure can.

Comment: Should be easy to find lots and lots of examples of this around the web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/infoBubbles/position-on-mouse-click
thats the answer, if someone is interested